# How do I set the base url for a django app?

Tags: python, django, user-accounts

I'm using the app [django-userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) to manage user accounts. I have it working, and can enable users to sign up, and they then receive an email to verify their account. However, I'm having difficulty figuring our where to change the base url, so that the email does not use `example.com`. For example, the email currently says:

> Thank you for signing up at example.com.
>
> To activate your account you should click on the link below:
>
> http://example.com/accounts/activate/14bd7b230525224b6bfd71ca4efd531d4694f857/
>
> Thanks for using our site!
>
> Sincerely, example.com

I understand that this is generated from the following template:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}{% load url from future %}
{% if not without_usernames %}{% blocktrans with user.username as username %}Dear {{ username }},{% endblocktrans %}
{% endif %}
{% blocktrans with site.name as site %}Thank you for signing up at {{ site }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "To activate your account you should click on the link below:" %}

{{ protocol }}://{{ site.domain }}{% url 'userena_activate' activation_key %}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% trans "Sincerely" %},
{{ site.name }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

However, I can't figure out where `example.com` is set - I've tried searching and looked through each file that has this, and I can't locate where I should (or if I should) be setting the url somewhere.

Comment: I think you can directly put that in the template: "http:// mysite.com{% url 'userena_activate' activation_key %}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably set in the [Django Sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) framework.  You should be able to edit the value through the admin or directly in the database.

Comment: Do I need to do more than just add `SITE_ID = 'http://mysite.com'` to my `settings.py` file? I tried this but the mail remained the same.

Comment: `SITE_ID` should be a number matching the ID of the site record in the database you want to use (if you're running a single site, that should always be 1).  You want to change the contents of that database record--it will be in the django_site table, and will have a `domain` and `name` field that will map into the `{{site.<whatever>}}` template variables.